# I want to "get" more than one "item"

Tags: php, forms, get

I want to send the "fill[]" and the "item[]" and my problem is the function write cant get the values of the variables, why?

What is wrong? Im new in this stuff.

```
<form action="/fill_sites/fill.php" method="get">

<input type="text" size="24" maxlength="20" name="fill[0]"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item[0]value="hella_apfelschorle"/>

<input type="text" size="24" maxlength="20" name="fill[1]"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item[1]" value="volvic_wasser"/>

..... so on

<input type="submit" value="Abschicken"/>

------------------------------------------------------------>[fill/php]>

$fill[0] = $_GET["fill[0]"];
$fill[1] = $_GET["fill[1]"];
$fill[2] = $_GET["fill[2]"];
$fill[3] = $_GET["fill[3]"];
$fill[4] = $_GET["fill[4]"];
$fill[5] = $_GET["fill[5]"];
$fill[6] = $_GET["fill[6]"];
$fill[7] = $_GET["fill[7]"];
$fill[8] = $_GET["fill[8]"];
$fill[9] = $_GET["fill[9]"];

$item[0] = $_GET["item[0]"];
$item[1] = $_GET["item[1]"];
$item[2] = $_GET["item[2]"];
$item[3] = $_GET["item[3]"];
$item[4] = $_GET["item[4]"];
$item[5] = $_GET["item[5]"];
$item[6] = $_GET["item[6]"];
$item[7] = $_GET["item[7]"];
$item[8] = $_GET["item[8]"];
$item[9] = $_GET["item[9]"];


            write($counterFilename[$item[]], $fill);
```

Comment: Why not only `$fill = $_GET['fill']` & `$item = $_GET['item']`? And `$counterFilename[$item[]]` should be `$counterFilename[$item]`. You are passing the value, not defining.

Comment: without [1] [2] ...?

Comment: Yup. They are `array`s.

Comment: `$fill[0] = $_GET['fill'][0];`

Comment: hm he dont gets the arrays :-/ i send the whole code, maybe you see the issue :/ html: pastebin.com/Sbx5efn2 php: pastebin.com/UNznxUQi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use php's foreach statement to retrieve the content of fill and item

```
$fills = $_GET['fill'];
foreach($fills as $fill)
{
    //do something with $fill
}
```

and the same for $item

Comment: Yes but my write function need both "item" and "fill", so i want to use the function, or isnt it possible?

http://pastebin.com/pMnsvddp

Comment: Its possible, you'll need to either pass them to your function or access them from within your function - you need to decide you you want your function/application to act. e.g; at the start of your func..
function write($counterFilename, $counter)
{
  //process item/fill - using foreach
//your function code
}

or your can call your function with the $item passed as a parem from within the loop
foreach($fills as $fill)
{
    write($counterFilename, $counter, $fill)
}
you'll need to adjust your function for that though...

Comment: ye  it works like this now:$item = $_GET["item"];
$fill = $_GET["fill"];

for ($i=0;$i < count($_GET["item"]); $i++) {
    write($counterFilename[$item[$i]], $fill[$i]);
}

Answer (score 3):

you can do this by following code. it will get complete array.

```
$item = $_Get['item'];
$fill= $_Get['fill'];
```

Comment: hm he dont gets the arrays :-/ i send the whole code, maybe you see the issue :/

html: http://pastebin.com/Sbx5efn2
php: http://pastebin.com/UNznxUQi

Comment: store complete array in this input field  `<input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="magnum_classic"/>` instead of  `<input type="hidden" name="item[0]" value="magnum_classic"/><input type="hidden" name="item[1]" value="cornetto_lemon"/>` etc and then get array. hopefully it will work

Comment: i did that and he still dont get it, maybe i did something wrong with the get command:http://pastebin.com/Fi5EYxVX

Comment: ok it works. Like this:$item = $_GET["item"];
$fill = $_GET["fill"];

for ($i=0;$i < count($_GET["item"]); $i++) {
    write($counterFilename[$item[$i]], $fill[$i]);
}

Comment: that's good i already let you know in comments it will work like this.

`$item = $_Get['item'];
$fill= $_Get['fill'];`